# Adding a file to an existing .debian file in java

Tags: java

I am looking for some pointers on how can I add a file into an existing .deb (debian) archive in Java ? Are there any libraries that I can use ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to unpack and repack the file. You can try running bash commands from java. The following answer suggests ways you can do that

[Java - Running Bash Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830617/java-running-bash-commands)

Refer to the following answer on how to unpack and repack .deb files.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138188/easily-unpack-deb-edit-postinst-and-repack-deb

**Edit:**

For a java library to do the same look at apache commons-compress.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/

Comment: Thank you. I am however looking to implement purely a java based solution that doesn't involve running bash commands.

Comment: oh then you should look at http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/ , apparently .deb files are implemented as an ar archive.

Comment: Thanks will experiment with that. Seems to have some file name limitation hopefully it will work out.