# How to write code for Jbutton so that by clicking it,it should open terminal prompt and we can able to execute commands in it

Tags: java, linux

How to open terminal prompt and run commands in linux. I have tried already

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a Terminal /path/to/the/executable");
```

This command. I have already tried many code but it doesn't give me answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830617/java-running-bash-commands

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Linux commands in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3403226/608639) and [How to invoke a Linux shell command from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1410741/608639). If you state what the problem or error is, or where you are having trouble, then you will probably get more specific answers.